# Android ImageButton made too big by it's image in background

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I am dynamically loading images to a image buttons on my screen. The images will not be known in advance and are diff size.

Does anyone know how to ensure the imagebutton size remains unaltered by whatever image is assigned to it. Preferably stretching the image to fit the button. I have tried using android:scaleType="fitXY" and setting th ewidth and height to hard values (not preferable). No matter what i do the image dictates the size of the button not vice versa! Help!

I tried a combo of the following. the images come randomly from a search of internet.

```
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/ImageButton1"
                        android:layout_height="93px"
                        android:src="@drawable/image1"
                        android:layout_width="93px"
                        android:background="93px" />
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/ImageButton4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/image1"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Much appreciated of any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of setting the size of each ImageButton, place the button in a container layout and set the size of the container. For example:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton1"
            android:src="@drawable/image1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</LinearLayout>
```

That should force your image button to be no bigger than the size of the container that it resides in.

Comment: this would help in ensuring the imagebutton sizes remain correct for the screen size/density of the device. thanks il give it a go.

Comment: I tried this method and the height part takes but the width doesnt change - I used the same layout as your example. Any ideas?

Comment: add android:scaleType="fitXY" attribute to your image.

Answer (score 1):

The bitmap you are having that are of different sizes. All of them can be transformed to newHeight and newWidth that might be suitable for you application.So size now will remain constant.Use code below make it of suitable width and height

```
Bitmap yourBitmap;
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

Comment: thanks il give that a go. I want my imagebutton sizes to change based on the size of the devices display density/size - do i need to do this through setting my imagebuttons sizes based on screen size then?

Comment: yes based on the size of device which you can get by getHeight() and getWidth() method you can decide size of ur images according to ur need

Comment: this seems to set the image inside the button to a good size but the grey button is still same size. is there some method i should use on the button itself?